# $P^{-1}AP$ vs. $PAP^{-1}$

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I am taking a course on ODE's and linear systems and I had a question about which formula to use, $P^{-1}AP$ or $PAP^{-1}$. My professor said it did not matter and that they give the same solution, but I have found that the solution is slightly different. For example, when exponentiating a Matrix \begin{bmatrix}
    2      & 6\\
     1     & -3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
when I solve the system, the answer for $P^{-1}AP$ and $PAP^{-1}$ have the $x_{21}$ and $x_{12}$ positions switched. (I am not going to write out the entire solution as it is long, but I can if requested!) I was wondering if this is still some how equivalent? Or can be overlooked somehow? I am just slightly confused because my professor says either is fine, and the book also switches between the two, but I get slightly different answers.

Answer (score 0):

The question is whether $P^{-1}AP$ or $QAQ^{-1}$ is correct. It depends on what $P$ and $Q$ are.

Answer is $P^{-1}AP$ if columns of $P$ consists of eigenvectors of $A$.

$$A \begin{bmatrix}v_1 & \ldots & v_n \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}v_1 & \ldots & v_n \end{bmatrix}diag(\lambda_1, \ldots,\lambda_n)$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}v_1 & \ldots & v_n \end{bmatrix}^{-1}A \begin{bmatrix}v_1 & \ldots & v_n \end{bmatrix}=diag(\lambda_1, \ldots,\lambda_n)$$

In this case, the relationship between $P$ and $Q$ is $Q=P^{-1}$.

Comment: So I should put the matrix of eigenvectors of A as the "last" matrix in the multiplication of the three technically?

Comment: yes, the one where the columns consists of the eigenvectors should be behind.

Comment: I was looking through my textbook and it looks like $P^{-1}$AP gives a Jordan Normal form, which we exponentiate to get some matrix call it D, but then to solve the IVP that is when we do x(t)= PD$P^{-1}x_0$?

Comment: why would $P^{-1}$ end up behind again? are you sure the two $P$ refers to the same thing?

Comment: Yes they are the same. Our textbook seems to do it this way. $P^{-1}$ in front seems to help us get the solution in y space, and then the other way in x space. So I may have answered my own question.